# How to override certain function in a module to disable the return value

Tags: hooks, theming

Not sure how to explain this clearly but let me try.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_footer()  to insert Javascript at the end of the page
 */
function omniture_footer($main = 0) {

  global $user;

    $header = "<!-- SiteCatalyst code version: ";
    $header .=  check_plain(variable_get("omniture_version", 'H.13.'));
    $header .= " Copyright 1997-2009 Omniture, Inc. More info available at http://www.omniture.com -->\n";
    $header .= "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"JavaScript\" src=\"";
    $header .=  check_plain(variable_get("omniture_js_file_location", 'http://www.example.com/js/s_code_remote_h.js'));
    $header .= "\"></script>\n";
    $header .= "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"JavaScript\"><!--\n";

    $footer = '/************* DO NOT ALTER ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ! **************/'."\n";
    $footer .= 'var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code)//--></script>'."\n";
    $footer .= '<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!--'."\n";
    $footer .= "if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE')>=0)document.write(unescape('%3C')+'\!-'+'-')"."\n";
    $footer .= '//--></script><noscript><a href="http://www.omniture.com" title="Web Analytics"><img src="';
    $footer .= check_plain(variable_get("omniture_image_file_location", 'http://examplecom.112.2O7.net/b/ss/examplecom/1/H.13--NS/0')).'/'.rand(0, 10000000).'"'."\n";
    $footer .= 'height="1" width="1" border="0" alt="" /></a></noscript><!--/DO NOT REMOVE/-->'."\n";
    $footer .= '<!-- End SiteCatalyst code version: ';
    $footer .=  check_plain(variable_get("omniture_version", 'H.13.'));
    $footer .= ' -->'."\n";

$script  = $header;
$script .= $extra_variables_formatted;
$script .= $footer;

return $script;
}
```

Now my task is to disable the $script to **not show** in unpublished articles. Is there any way to do this in template.php preprocess?

**Note: The below solved my question. Its 100% working in my end. Thanks**

```
//Remove omniture tags in unpublish node
  if(arg(0) == 'node' && $vars['node']->status == 0) {
    $vars['closure'] = theme('closure');
    $omnitureTags = preg_replace( "/\<!-- SiteCatalyst code version: H\.19\.4 Copyright 1997-2009.+\<!-- End SiteCatalyst code version: H\.19\.4 --\>/si", "", $vars['closure']);
    $vars['closure'] = $omnitureTags;
  } else {
    $vars['closure'] = theme('closure');
  }
```

Put the above code in **preprocess_page**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned from the implementations of `hook_footer()` is used from [theme('closure')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_closure/6).

```
function theme_closure($main = 0) {
  $footer = module_invoke_all('footer', $main);
  return implode("\n", $footer) . drupal_get_js('footer');
}
```

That function is called from [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6), which uses the following code:

```
  // Closure should be filled last.
  $variables['closure']           = theme('closure');

  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $variables['node'] = $node;
  }
```

If you want not to print the value returned by `hook_footer()`, you have the following options. As you are talking of articles, I get you mean nodes whose content type is "article"; if you used the word *articles* to mean nodes, then remove the part that checks the value of the `type` property.

- Empty `$variables['closure']` inside a preprocess function, which can be implemented in a module, or a theme (inside template.php). The following code is the code I would write for a theme.

  ```
  function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if (!empty($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type == 'article' && !$variables['node']->status) {
      $variables['closure'] = '';
    }
  }
  ```

  If you are not interested in the content type of the node, then the code becomes the following one:

  ```
  function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if (!empty($variables['node']) && !$variables['node']->status) {
      $variables['closure'] = '';
    }
  }
  ```
- In the page.tpl.php file you normally find the following code to print the value returned from `hook_footer()`:

  ```
  <?php print $closure; ?>
  ```

  Replace that line with the following one:

  ```
  <?php if (!empty($node) && $node->type != 'article' && $node->status): ?>
    <?php print $closure; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  ```

  If you just need not to print the value of `$closure` when a node is not published, independently from the content type of the node, then the code simply becomes:

  ```
  <?php if (!empty($node) && $node->status): ?>
    <?php print $closure; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  ```

In this way, you can remove the value added to `$closure` from all the implementations of `hook_footer()`. You can also remove the part added from a specific module, if the module always adds the same string.

If you want to change the value returned from your implementation of `hook_footer()`, you can use `menu_get_object()` to get the node object associated to the page, if there is one.

```
function mymodule_footer() {
  $node = menu_get_object();

  if (!empty($node) && $node->type == 'article' && !$node->status) {
    return '';
  }

  // Return the value you would return when the node is published.
}
```

Comment: @kiamlaluno...not sure about this part "published): ?>". Can you please elaborate more..thank you for responding in my query.

Comment: The code was simply not correctly indented. I am sorry for not having noted it.

Comment: Shouldn't published be status? :)

Comment: @Berdir ...sorry what do you mean? Basically all I want is to disable the script in unpublished articles... kiamlaluno's answer looks promising but no idea how to execute it in my end...so clueless at this time

Comment: @Berdir Yes, it should. That is happens when I answer a question after I didn't sleep. `:-)`

Comment: OK, now the answer is complete.

Comment: @kiamlaluno really thanks for the great answer...well said...sorry mate still a newbie trying to get learn Drupal...one question since the $script contains many scripts not generated by all hook_footer...is there a way to just exclude the script returned by omniture_footer...not sure if that's still doable...

Comment: @ninjascorner You can, but you need to find the string added by that module, and replace it with an empty string. It should not be difficult, as the script starts with "`<!-- SiteCatalyst code version:`" and ends with "`<!-- End SiteCatalyst code version: `". Using `preg_replace()`, and the right regular expression, you can remove the full script. Remember that the regular expression needs to match also the version number reported at the end, and the "`-->`" part, or the that part will be output in the footer (as it is not included anymore in a HTML comment).

Comment: @kiamlaluno really thanks now everything is all clear to me...